# How to answer to a rude comment

Tags: discussion, support, flags, comments

I have asked this question : [DTEXEC.exe for running an SSIS 2013 package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062071/dtexec-exe-for-running-an-ssis-2013-package/35142046?noredirect=1#comment58093537_35142046)

To this question I got the comment below.

> You are wasting everyones time - that is a ridiculous restriction
>   which you should've stated upfront. – Mike Honey 12 hours ago

If mr Mike Honey would have checked out the only two comments for the question, he would have seen the answer to his remark.

My question is: 
In cases like this, how should one proceed?
Was I out of line with my sarcasm by responding with the comment below?

> thank you for the very friendly comment. From a site full with
>   brilliant programmers, one would expect that a problem might have been
>   encountered before and therefore one might provide a solution for the
>   current setup and offering as a solution installing additional
>   components. I'm sure your comment makes SO a better place. Keep up the
>   good work! ps: I said i can work ONLY with what I have, days before
>   you posted your answer. I can only imagine how much time you've
>   'wasted' since you didn't even read the only two comments for this question

Notes: I didn't find an answer on the internet which worked for my problem, so I decided to reward the answer with a bounty of 50 since. Am I really wasting the reader's time? IMHO, it's a good question for someone which has the same version of SSIS and SQL server as me. I guess i'm not the only one ;).

Thank you for your time and thoughts!

Comment: Flag it...as rude or offensive.

Comment: forgot to say I also got a downvote from mr. Honey. Since his comment and the downvote occured at the same time, i'm pretty sure it was him.

Comment: You can't be *certain* is was, as DV are anonymous, and people are free to vote as they choose. The comment will be handled, you'll just have to live with the DV.

Comment: @CM2K: Voting is anonymous, don't make assumptions about the comment and the vote. For all you know the comment and vote coincided by accident.

Comment: also made a small mistake in my comment. `without offering as a solution installing additional components`. But I guess, it's understandable

Comment: @CM2K Never answer to such comment. Just flag it. Moderators can handle such a peoples. That's why moderators here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, but when your question doesn't get any votes for days, or new views in a couple of hours time frame and then you see a comment and a downvote at the same time. Coincidence? Maybe, but yet again, in this case, maybe not

Comment: on a funny side, I'm getting downvotes here too. Maybe mr Honey saw this post :)

Comment: Not sure I would classify this comment as "rude", if it is a reasonable interpretation of your question (I can't really tell).

Comment: @Pekka웃 maybe it would have had a reasonable interpretation if there wasn't already a comment which contained the information which was seeking. Information which clearly stated that I have to work with what I have. Because his solution sounds a bit like this. OP: I have this problem i have to solve on windows 7. Answer from a guy: Do it on windows 8, what you are trying to do is wasting people's time.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough.

Comment: Flag and move on...

Comment: what should I have includded to this question to make it clearer/better ? asking you downvoters. I would like to improve the quality of my questions and yes I have read Jon Skeet's tutorial

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You *don't* respond. You flag it as rude and **move on**.

Leave it to moderators to handle such behaviour and comments, don't lower yourself to their level.

I've cleaned up the comments now.

At the same time, if someone is making remarks about assumptions or restrictions missing from your question, in whatever manner those remarks may have been delivered, consider updating your question to make those assumptions or restrictions clearer. Always ask yourself if you can improve your question to avoid such responses.

Comment: thank you, I am really hoping for an answer for my problem. It actually made me consider that my question isn't good enough since someone with a high reputation told me that `im wasting everybody's time`

Comment: @CM2K: One rude user (whatever their reputation) doesn't make for a valid complaint. Don't take it too seriously.